# Confirm email server side validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I’m trying to achieve some server side validation for email i.e. when the user picks option from the form that there preferred way of communication is either Mobile, or Telephone but they enter their email address in the email text box of the form and leave confirm email address blank, server side should still throw up validation that confirm email does not match even though there preferred way of communication is Mobile or Telephone.

Please see my statement below:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Email) && Email != ConfirmEmailAddress)
{
    yield return new ValidationResult("Please ensure confirm email matches", new[] { "ConfirmEmailAddress" }); //returns message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `||` instead of `&&`.

Your current statement is saying "If email is null/empty, AND email does not equal to confirmation email." when it should be "If email is null/empty, OR email does not equal to confirmation email."

Comment: Now confirm email address is always mandotory even if its null @ThePerplexedOne

Comment: I don't want it to always be mandatory even if its null @Sam i want confirm email validation to throw up only if user types in a valid email address in there.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the condition to :

```
if (isPrefferedWayOfCommunication != mobileOrTelephone && emailIsNotNull && email != confirmEmail) {
 showEmailConfirmationError();
}
```

Comment: something like this?             if (this.CCommmunication == Commmunication.Email && ConfirmEmailAddress != Email)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Please ensure confirm email matches", new[] { "ConfirmEmailAddress" }); //returns message
            }

Comment: Right, this is better if the user has option to select communication mode as "Email" too.

Answer (score 0):

I was jsut missing the ! operator before string

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Email) && Email != ConfirmEmailAddress)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Please ensure confirm email matches", new[] { "ConfirmEmailAddress" }); //returns message
            }
```